# android:excludeFromRecents with Game Maker

Tags: android-activity

I need to exclude my app from the recent apps when closing it. I think I already found the solution but due to I'm new to java programming **I don't know where to find the activity-section and the android:excludeFromRecents function** (?).

Thanks for any help! J